# POWER BI FILTRO

Tags: powerbi

Tengo problemas con un reporte que consiste en cargar una base de datos con:

- Una columna Tipo de producto dentro de la cual puede ser juguetes, perfumes, deportivas.
- Otra columna con fechas
- Y otra columna con ventas

He creado una Medida llamada Ranking la cual clasifica por ventas el tipo de producto y otra medida calculando su percentil.

El problema viene cuando veo que ese ranking no tiene en cuenta el filtro de tipo de producto y me calcula el ranking y el percentil sobre toda la base de datos.

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

creo que con ALLSELECTED dentro de una formula CALCULATE puedes resolver el problema, te envio un enlace para que puedas profundizar https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/allselected-function-dax